# vertx-service-proxy: Access the underlying message header?

Tags: vert.x

I am building a data access service and found service proxies to be quite comfortable.

Now I want to authenticate against them. With plain old eventbus listener I would put this kind of information into the header of my message.

One possibility would be to put my token in the signature of each method. But I don't want to clutter my api with authentication stuff.

Questions:

- Is it possible to use custom message headers using the proxy code generated by @ProxyGen annotation?
- Is there another way to secure these services?